# what exactly happens two threads reach to increment the atomic integers at same time

Tags: multithreading

Consider the following scenario:

Thread 1 calls get and gets the value 1.
Thread 1 calculates next to be 2.
Thread 2 calls get and gets the value 1.
Thread 2 calculates next to be 2.
Both threads try to write the value.
Now because of atomics - only one thread will succeed, the other will recieve false from the compareAndSet and go around again.
I got stuck at "because of atomics" what if two threads pass compareandset method at sametime . I am looking for practical examples than theory.

Comment: Do you have a code example of this?

Comment: The hardware will serialize the operations. There is only one main memory system, and only one processor at a time can use it. The processors (or really, their cache controllers) negotiate access to main memory via hardware protocols.

Comment: i do not have any i am looking for code examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hardware interlocks will ensure that if two or more threads attempt a compareAndSet simultaneously, one will be selected as "winning" and all others will "lose".  Typically this will be done by using a common clock for all cores, so that every core will see a discrete sequence of execution steps (called "cycles" at the hardware level) in which 
various things happen.  In a vastly over-simplified execution model where cores don't have caches but instead use a multi-port memory, each core could report to every other core on each cycle whether it is performing the "read" portion of a compareAndSet.  Each core would then hold off on starting a compareAndSet on the cycle after it has seen another thread start one, and each core could defer and restart its own compareAndSet if a lower-numbered core starts one with the same address on the same cycle.

The net result is that it's impossible for two cores to "successfully" perform compareAndSet operations on the same storage at the same time.  Instead, hardware will delay one of the actions so that they occur sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

It is the hardware, specifically the cache coherence protocol ([MESI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol), etc.) that's ensuring the consistency of atomic operations done concurrently from different CPU cores (which run respective concurrent threads). There is a good reading called "Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers" which I can highly recommend on the subject.